# Delphi - how i can use TChart with IntraWeb

Tags: delphi, teechart, intraweb

I'm using `Delphi XE8` with `IntraWeb` XIV v14.0.49 i create a `TIWForm` and i drooped a `TChart` component on it.

On the design time the `TChart` displayed and i can set it up.

But on the run time there is no `TChart` on the web page.

Is there any setting should i configure to use it ?

Comment: Are you using TeeChart library that ships with Delphi or a PRO version of TeeChart library? As far as I know you need a PRO version of TeeChart library in order to be able to use TChart component in IntraWeb applications.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, I'm using TeeChart library that ships with Delphi. But as per the feature matrix of TeeChart lib on their website it seems support IntraWeb https://www.steema.com/feature_matrix/vcl check the `TeeChart Standard in RAD Studio`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you must use the `TChart` with `TIWImage` to display it in the webpage.

I found the following method in IntraWeb demos

```
// this method copies a TChart to an TIWImage
procedure CopyChartToImage(const aChart: TChart; const aImage: TIWImage);
var
  xMetaFile: TMetafile;
  xBitmap: TBitmap;
  xRect: TRect;
begin
  xBitmap := aImage.Picture.Bitmap;
  xBitmap.Width := aChart.Width;
  xBitmap.Height := aChart.Height;
  aImage.Width := aChart.Width;
  aImage.Height := aChart.Height;

  xRect := Rect(0, 0, aChart.Width, aChart.Height);
  aChart.BufferedDisplay := False;
  xMetaFile := aChart.TeeCreateMetafile(False, xRect);
  try
    xBitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, xMetaFile);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(xMetaFile);
  end;
end;
```

[For more information](http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/Download/IntraWebDemos.EN.aspx)